# prototype or singleton spring bean is better when request consumers are high and incoming requests are growing to peak

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, architecture

There is an External source will post the request --> Kafka --> Kafka Consumer calls MyComputation's business logic. Assume that these are deployed in the cloud (AWS or Azure whatever cloud we can), we have Kafka Cluster with 4 nodes, and Kafka consumer service with 4 nodes *[Note: `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` is used in both the below options]*. All 8 Linux VM's with 2 Core, 2GB RAM (just for reference this is not much important in my question)

**Option-1:**

1. There is a unit of some complex business logic (`CPU & Memory intensive, but not IO intensive`) in spring bean called MyComputation.java (with spring bean scope `prototype`) to safeguard from concurrency issues, or to have it thread-safe.
2. We have Kafka consumer to receive the requests from external service
3. Kafka consumer has a logic that calls `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` getBean() at runtime to get the prototype bean of MyComputation.java and executes the complex business logic inside it.

**Option-2:**

1. There is a unit of some complex business logic (`CPU & Memory intensive, but not IO intensive`) in spring bean called MyComputation.java (with spring bean scope `singleton`) and make our logic with some thread safety handling mechanism.
2. We have Kafka consumer to receive the requests from external service
3. Kafka consumer has a logic that will have autowired MyComputation.java class (with `singleton` by default) and call the business logic and avoid creating the entire bean object per request.

Now, my doubt is which one is the better Option-1 or 2? when the rate of computation execution time is lower than the rate of the incoming requests. And I have been asked to opt one option out of 2 mentioned above beyond anything we might want to increase hardware we can add. But the intent of the question is to choose the better option mentioned above.

***Please suggest to me which option is better Option #1 or #2??***

Comment: Did you try to run some performance tests? I suggest you to use concurrent Kafka listeners instead (configure the `concurrency` parameter). See: [ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#message-listener-container).

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Question is more towards opting `prototype` bean or `singleton`, as `prototype` beans creation per request is going to be consuming huge memory, and I have been asked to design consumer logic should not increase consuming memory gradually higher side and certainly reach OOM.